# Count the clicks on an item of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing an android app in which I use a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html). Suppose I have 6 items in my `RecyclerView` i.e. `[A, B, C, D, E, F]`. So how can I get the number of clicks on these items?

For example:

If an user open item `B` 4 times. How can I get the `count = 4`?

P.s. `count` should increase only when the user click on the **same** item.

Comment: I have done that. I need to count the clicks on that particular item. @GiacomoLai

Comment: could you post how did you populate the data in recyclerview and how are you applying onCLick on recyclerview?

Answer (score 1):

First declare static count variables for each items

```
private static int aCount = 0;
```

Then inside your onBindViewHolder, pass a method after the button click along with your position id.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                    thisWasClicked(position);

               }
    }
}
```

The method will be something like this

```
private void thisWasClicked(int position) {

    if (position == 0) {
        aCount++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in holder

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(){

    onClick(){
        // count up
    }
}
```

each item needs also an `id` to know, which item it is

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Map<Integer, Integer> clicksMap = new HashMap<>()` in your adapter

You should also pass an interface to your ViewHolder that acts as a click Listener. Something like.

```
public interface OnItemLick { 
 void onItemClick(int position, int id);
}
```

Then declare an instance of this interface in your adapter.

```
    OnItemLick listener = new OnItemClick() {   
        void onItemClick(int position, int id) {
          //you can either use the item position or an id (if you have an unique one for the items). I will show an example using the position.
          int count;
          if(clicksMap.contains(position)) { 
            count = clickMap.get(position);
            count ++;
            clickMap.put(position, count);
          }else {
            count ++;
            clickMap.put(position, count);   } 
         }
```

In the end you clicksMap will contain the click count for every position of the items in the recycler.

Answer (score 0):

I've made an example

**CustomItem** object

```
public class CustomItem {

private String item;
private int click;

public String getItem() {
    return item;
}

public void setItem(String item) {
    this.item = item;
}

public int getClick() {
    return click;
}

public void setClick(int click) {
    this.click = click;
}
```

}

**CustomAdapter** and **CustomViewHolder** for the recyclerview

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

private List<CustomItem> itemList;

public CustomAdapter(List<CustomItem> itemList){
    this.itemList = itemList;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new CustomViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewholder_generic, parent, false));;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
         //increase click count for the current item
         itemList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setClick(itemList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getClick() + 1);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemList.size();
}

// Custom ViewHolder
public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    //add fields you need

    public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
}
```